# Remove whitespace from string excluding parts between pairs of " and ' C++

Tags: c++, string, c++11, whitespace, string-parsing

So essentially what I want to do is erase all the whitespace from an `std::string` object, however excluding parts within speech marks and quote marks (so basically strings), eg:

```
Hello, World! I am a string
```

Would result in:

```
Hello,World!Iamastring
```

However things within speech marks/quote marks would be ignored:

```
"Hello, World!" I am a string
```

Would result in:

```
"Hello, World!"Iamastring
```

Or:

```
Hello,' World! I' am a string
```

Would be:

```
Hello,' World! I'amastring
```

Is there a simple routine to perform this to a string, either one build into the standard library or an example of how to write my own? It doesn't have to be the most efficient one possible, as it will only be run once or twice every time the program runs.

Comment: _"Is there a simple routine to perform this to a string?"_ Nothing ready made I'm aware of.

Comment: My bad, I phrased that wrong.

Comment: @Joe They're being pedantic :))

Comment: Can you give it a go yourself and then ask when you get stuck? Off-hand, I can think of several different approaches.

Comment: I'll give it a go; I kind of can.

Comment: I tried to cook up a regex. Now I have 2 problems to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***No***, there is not such a routine ready.

You may build your own though.

You have to loop over the string and you want to use a flag. If the flag is true, then you delete the spaces, if it is false, you ignore them. The flag is true when you are not in a part of quotes, else it's false.

Here is a naive, not widely tested example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // we will copy the result in new string for simplicity
    // of course you can do it inplace. This takes into account only
    // double quotes. Easy to extent do single ones though!
    string str("\"Hello, World!\" I am a string");
    string new_str = "";
    // flags for when to delete spaces or not
    // 'start' helps you find if you are in an area of double quotes
    // If you are, then don't delete the spaces, otherwise, do delete
    bool delete_spaces = true, start = false;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i) {
        if(str[i] == '\"') {
            start ? start = false : start = true;
            if(start) {
                delete_spaces = false;
            }
        }
        if(!start) {
            delete_spaces = true;
        }
        if(delete_spaces) {
            if(str[i] != ' ') {
                new_str += str[i];
            }
        } else {
            new_str += str[i];
        }

    }
    cout << "new_str=|" << new_str << "|\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> new_str=|"Hello, World!"Iamastring|

Comment: Thanks. I'll take this approach and see if I can do it.

Comment: You are welcome @Joe. Since you are new here, I posted some code too. However, next time you ask, make sure you post your attempt too!

Comment: Thanks @gsamaras :). I forgot about using if-this?then-this:otherwise-this to flip the flag. I'll post what I came up with, basically iterating through the string, flipping the flag if there's a " or ', while removing whitespace if the flag is false.

Answer (score 3):

Here we go. I ended up iterating through the string, and if it finds either a `"` or a `'`, it will flip the ignore flag. If the ignore flag is true and the current character is not a `"` or a `'`, the iterator just increments until it either reaches the end of the string or finds another `"`/`'`. If the ignore flag is false, it will remove the current character if it's whitespace (either space, newline or tab).

EDIT: this code now supports ignoring escaped characters (`\"`, `\'`) and making sure a string starting with a `"` ends with a `"`, and a string starting with a `'` ends with a `'`, ignoring anything else in between.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string str("I am some code, with \"A string here\", but not here\\\". 'This sentence \" should not end yet', now it should. There is also 'a string here' too.\n");
    std::string::iterator endVal = str.end(); // a kind of NULL pointer
    std::string::iterator type = endVal;      // either " or '
    bool ignore = false; // whether to ignore the current character or not
    for (std::string::iterator it=str.begin(); it!=str.end();)
    {
        // ignore escaped characters
        if ((*it) == '\\')
        {
            it += 2;
        }
        else
        {
            if ((*it) == '"' || (*it) == '\'')
            {
                if (ignore) // within a string
                {
                    if (type != endVal && (*it) == (*type))
                    {
                        // end of the string
                        ignore = false;
                        type = endVal;
                    }
                }
                else // outside of a string, so one must be starting.
                {
                    type = it;
                    ignore = true;
                }
                it++;
                //ignore ? ignore = false : ignore = true;
                //type = it;
            }
            else
            {
                if (!ignore)
                {
                    if ((*it) == ' ' || (*it) == '\n' || (*it) == '\t')
                    {
                        it = str.erase(it);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        it++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    it++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "string now is: " << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OK good Joe, you have shown that you tried a lot. I upvoted both your question and your answer, keep it that way! Now, just mark an answer you like as accepted and you are done!

Comment: Cool :) I'm trying to add the ignore-escape-character functionality from @Dúthomhas, and also make sure that it only stops ignoring when it's found an identical match (ie: " to " and ' to '). Should I edit the code above after this, and because I've taken things from both yours and Dúthomhas' answer, which one would be best marked correct? My own?

Comment: Joe, it is up to you if you edit your answer. Same goes for which answer to accept. Personally, I've never accepted my own answer when other answers lie in the same area.

Answer (score 2):

Argh, and here I spent time writing this (simple) version:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <ciso646>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename Predicate>
std::string remove_unquoted_chars( const std::string& s, Predicate p )
{
  bool skip = false;
  char q = '\0';
  std::string result;

  for (char c : s)
    if (skip) 
    {
      result.append( 1, c );
      skip = false;
    }
    else if (q)
    {
      result.append( 1, c );
      skip = (c == '\\');
      if (c == q) q = '\0';
    }
    else 
    {
      if (!std::isspace( c )) 
        result.append( 1, c );
      q = p( c ) ? c : '\0';
    }

  return result;
}

std::string remove_unquoted_whitespace( const std::string& s )
{
  return remove_unquoted_chars( s, []( char c ) -> bool { return (c == '"') or (c == '\''); } );
}

int main()
{
  std::string s;
  std::cout << "s? ";
  std::getline( std::cin, s );
  std::cout << remove_unquoted_whitespace( s ) << "\n";
}
```

Removes all characters identified by the given predicate *except* stuff inside a single-quoted or double-quoted C-style string, taking care to respect escaped characters.

Comment: Aah, thanks :) - I didn't remember to include escape character exemption, that'll be the next step as well as ignoring a speech mark inside a quote mark, and vice versa. As a quick (small) question, are escape characters always a backslash followed by one character or possibly more?

Comment: In C and C++, yes. The above code, for simplicity, simply ignores all such characters, but in C and C++ it is only meaningful for a small subset of characters. The code presumes well-formed quotations.

Comment: Thanks, I've added a bit that just iterates over the escaped character which should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

you may use erase-remove idiom like this

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>


int main()
{
    std::string str("\"Hello, World!\" I am a string");

    std::size_t x = str.find_last_of("\"");
    std::string split1 = str.substr(0, ++x);
    std::string split2 = str.substr(x, str.size());

    split1.erase(std::remove(split1.begin(), split1.end(), '\\'), split1.end());

    split2.erase(std::remove(split2.begin(), split2.end(), ' '), split2.end());

    std::cout << split1 + split2;
}
```